# Setting up PostCSS

Tags: plugins, gulp, postcss

I am just trying to set up PostCSS and integrate it into my recent workflow. But somehow I don't seem to get it work.

I am using A Mac and gulp as a task runner.

This is the erro I get when starting my watch task:

> TypeError: $.postcss is not a function

And this is what my gulpfile.js looks like:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({
  rename: {
    'browser-sync': 'browserSync',
    'gulp-postcss': 'postcss',
  },
  pattern: ['gulp-*', 'gulp.*', 'del', 'run-sequence', 'browser-sync'],
  DEBUG: false
});



var targetPath = 'dist';

var useBrowserSync = $.util.env.browserSync || true;


gulp.task('sass', function(){
  return gulp.src('src/scss/*.{scss,sass,css}')
    .pipe($.postcss([
        require('precss')()
      ], {syntax: require('postcss-scss')}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(targetPath + '/public/assets/css'))
    .pipe( $.if( useBrowserSync , $.browserSync.stream() ) );
});

gulp.task('watch', ['sass'], function(){
  if( useBrowserSync ){
   $.browserSync.create();

   $.browserSync.init({
     proxy: 'localhost/my_project/dist/public/'
   });
  }

  gulp.watch('src/scss/*.{scss,sass,css}', ['sass']);
});
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: have you tried to require postcss without gulp-load-plugins. What does Console say when you log it?